# Pass command line variables between Python files. Totally stuck

Tags: python, variables, import, command

I have what seems like a very easy problem with an easy solution just beyond my reach.

My setup:

A) Driver file (runs the test script)
B) Connection file (using Requests)
C) Parameters file

The paramenters file has 6 variables with things like server IP, login, pass etc.

The Driver file has a praser which reads the properties file and fills in the blanks.

> driver.py paramtersfile.csv

This works fine. However, I added a PORT variable to the parameters file which needs to be seen by B) Connection file. This connections file is never called explicitly, rather just imported into the driver file for its connection and cookie methods.

How do I carry over the parsed variables (from sys.argv) from paramtersfile.csv to the Connections file (or any other file which is used to run my script?

Thank you stackoverflow community

Edit:

I got it to work using the obvious way of passing on the arguments into the class (self.foo) of whatever module/file I needed.

My question from before was along the lines of this idea:

You do something like

loadproperties(propertiesfile)

then from any other python script you could just do

import propertyloader

which would load a list of immutable properties into the current space

Seems very convenient to just do

url = propertyloader.url

instead of

class Connect (host, port, pass, **url**):

self.**url** = **url**

loader = requests(secure, **url**)

blah blah blah...

Seems like a headache free way of sharing common parameters between different parts of the script.

Maybe there's still a way of doing this (extra credit question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the driver.py file, import the connections file as a module and pass the arguments you've parsed to the methods inside the module. Something like this:

```
#===inside driver.py===
import connections

params = parseFile(sys.argv) #get parameters from the csv file that is passed to the command line
connections.connect(params)  #pass them to whatever method you need to call from connections
```

**EDIT:** It sounds like you're not writing your code in a modular way. You should stop thinking about your code in terms of files, but instead think of them in terms of modules: bits and pieces of interchangeable code that you can use in many different places. The main flaw with your design that I see (forgive me if I didn't understand correctly) is that you're hard-coding a value inside the connections file that you use to create connection objects. I'm guessing this is what your code looks like (or at least captures the spirit of your code adequately):

```
#connections.py
MY_SERVER = ??? #WHAT DO I SET THIS TO?

class Connection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = MY_SERVER

def connect():
    connection = Connection() #create a new connection object
```

The above code is not designed well since you're defining a variable `MY_SERVER` that shouldn't be defined there in the first place! The connections class doesn't know or care what server it should use, it should work with any server. So where do you get the server variable? You pass it in via a constructor or a method. You could do something like this:

```
#connections.py
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, server):
        self.server = server

def connect(server):
    connection = Connection(server) #create a new connection object with the server passed to the method
```

With this design, the Connection object becomes much more flexible. It is basically saying "I am a connection object that can handle any server. If you want to use me, just tell me what server you want to use!".

This way, in your drivers file you can first parse the server from your csv, and then simply call the method `connections.connect` by passing it the server you want!

Comment: Thank you for the reply:

However - 

The connections file has 1 variable outside of any classes and methods which is 

server = ip:port

That server is used to build the connection object.
So I suppose my confusion is what do I set the server = to?

The idea would be something like

server = driver.praseFile(sys.argv) but that wouldn't work being called from the connections file, as driver isn't being imported.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hopefully I've understood your problem correctly. Tell me if there's anything that isn't clear.

Comment: Edit:

Thanks once more Lanaru. I'm taking your advice and trying it out.
Again, I appreciate the time it took for you to write out your detailed response.

Comment: Of course! Make sure to accept the answer if it works out. :)

Comment: Lanaru, 

I'm afraid I'm wearing out your good will, but I would really love it if you could answer, in a few words (possible or not, easy or not) my edit on the original question. Much thanks.